# The mysteries of an overloaded operator's body

Tags: c++, function, class, reference, operator-overloading

Let's say I've the following classes:

Trees and Tree;

Object Trees holds an array of Tree objects.

Here are the contents of the Trees and Tree classes:

Trees.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Tree.h"

class Trees
{
private:
    Tree m_Tree[20];
    int iTrees;

public:
    Trees(void) : iTrees(0){}

    Tree GetTree(int i){ return m_Tree[i];}

    void AddTree(Tree tree){ m_Tree[iTrees++] = tree;}

};
```

Tree.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Tree
{

private:
    std::string Name;
    bool HasRelatives;

public:
    Tree(void):HasRelatives(0){};

    Tree(std::string name):Name(name), HasRelatives(0){};


    std::string GetName(){ return Name;}

    void SetName(std::string name){ Name = name;}

    bool GetHasRelatives(){ return HasRelatives;}

    void SetHasRelatives(bool alone){ HasRelatives = alone;}


    bool operator == (Tree & tree)
    {
        if(this->GetName() == tree.GetName())
        {
            this->SetHasRelatives(1);

            tree.SetHasRelatives(1);

            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

};
```

And let's say I'm using the classes like this (main.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Trees.h"


int main()
{
    Trees Trees;

    Trees.AddTree(Tree("Oak"));

    Trees.AddTree(Tree("Oak"));


    if(Trees.GetTree(0) == Trees.GetTree(1))
    {

        std::cout<<"Trees are the same" << std::endl;

        if(Trees.GetTree(1).GetHasRelatives() == 1)
            std::cout<<"Tree has relatives" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To my current understanding, the program should output "Tree has relatives", because the second Tree ( Trees.GetTree(1) ) is passed by reference, thus any changes made inside the == operator's body should be visible outside it...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What a beautiful question name.

Comment: Well, I might have overdone with that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the sematics of `operator==` to mutate its arguments are questionable, your specific problem is that you are returning copies from `GetTree`:

```
Tree GetTree(int i){ return m_Tree[i];}
```

hence **the copies are modified** when you apply `==` and then they are thrown away. When you call `GetTree` again, the new copies are, of course, not modified.

What you would need is

```
Tree& GetTree(int i){ return m_Tree[i];}
```

to be able to modify the tree stored inside `m_Tree[i]`.